# change last folder without trailing slash from url

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to change

> http://www.site.asia/nw/aboutUs/myanenghp

to

> http://www.site.asia/nw/aboutUs/myan

There's alot of url like first one. Therefore, to be clarify, I would like to replace every

> myanenghp

with

> myan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/myanenghp$ $1/myan
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)myanenghp$ /$1myan [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want to externally redirect, remove the `,R=301` from the square brackets.